# Swipe button menu in jetpack compose

Tags: android, button, android-jetpack-compose

I wanna implement a swipe button menu which get bigger and brighter when in the center and the others are smaller and darker. And wanna implement it in jetpack compose. Looking foward for a solution

[image: Swipe button menu]

Comment: its possible using pager in compose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible with pager inspired from https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/effects/photo-filter-carousel. The problem i think with pager is not smooth fling i guess. Other than that it fits the use case.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalPagerApi::class, ExperimentalSnapperApi::class)
@Composable
fun PagerDemo(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    BoxWithConstraints(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        val contentPadding = (maxWidth - 50.dp) / 2
        val offSet = maxWidth / 5
        val itemSpacing = offSet - 50.dp
        val pagerState = rememberPagerState()
        val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

        HorizontalPager(
            count = 30,
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = contentPadding),
            modifier = modifier,
            itemSpacing = itemSpacing,
            state = pagerState
        ) { page ->
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(50.dp)
                    .graphicsLayer {
                        val pageOffset = calculateCurrentOffsetForPage(page).absoluteValue
                        // Set the item alpha and scale based on the distance from the center
                        val percentFromCenter = 1.0f - (pageOffset / (5f / 2f))
                        val itemScale = 0.5f + (percentFromCenter * 0.5f).coerceIn(0f, 1f)
                        val opacity = 0.25f + (percentFromCenter * 0.75f).coerceIn(0f, 1f)

                        alpha = opacity
                        scaleY = itemScale
                        scaleX = itemScale
                        shape = CircleShape
                        clip = true
                    }
                    .background(color = colors[page % colors.size])
                    .clickable(
                        interactionSource = MutableInteractionSource(),
                        indication = null,
                        enabled = true,
                    ) {
                        scope.launch {
                            pagerState.animateScrollToPage(page)
                        }
                    })
        }
    }
}


private val colors = listOf(
    Color.Red,
    Color.Green,
    Color.Blue,
    Color.Magenta,
    Color.Yellow,
    Color.Cyan,
)
```

Screen shot
[image]

The second way is inspired from a blog on medium https://fvilarino.medium.com/recreating-google-podcasts-speed-selector-in-jetpack-compose-7623203a009d. Here i guess instead of scroll to certain position on click may be we should think of animate or smooth scroll to center based on the item clicked.

```
private val colors = listOf(
    Color.Red,
    Color.Green,
    Color.Blue,
    Color.Magenta,
    Color.Yellow,
    Color.Cyan,
)

@Stable
interface CarouselState {
    val currentValue: Float
    val range: ClosedRange<Int>

    suspend fun snapTo(value: Float)
    suspend fun scrollTo(value: Int)
    suspend fun decayTo(velocity: Float, value: Float)
    suspend fun stop()
}

class CarouselStateImpl(
    currentValue: Float,
    override val range: ClosedRange<Int>,
) : CarouselState {
    private val floatRange = range.start.toFloat()..range.endInclusive.toFloat()
    private val animatable = Animatable(currentValue)
    private val decayAnimationSpec = FloatSpringSpec(
        dampingRatio = Spring.DampingRatioLowBouncy,
        stiffness = Spring.StiffnessLow,
    )
    override val currentValue: Float
        get() = animatable.value

    override suspend fun stop() {
        animatable.stop()
    }

    override suspend fun snapTo(value: Float) {
        animatable.snapTo(value.coerceIn(floatRange))
    }

    override suspend fun scrollTo(value: Int) {
        animatable.snapTo(value.toFloat().coerceIn(floatRange))
    }

    override suspend fun decayTo(velocity: Float, value: Float) {
        val target = value.roundToInt().coerceIn(range).toFloat()
        animatable.animateTo(
            targetValue = target,
            initialVelocity = velocity,
            animationSpec = decayAnimationSpec,
        )
    }

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false

        other as CarouselStateImpl

        if (range != other.range) return false
        if (floatRange != other.floatRange) return false
        if (animatable != other.animatable) return false
        if (decayAnimationSpec != other.decayAnimationSpec) return false

        return true
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        var result = range.hashCode()
        result = 31 * result + floatRange.hashCode()
        result = 31 * result + animatable.hashCode()
        result = 31 * result + decayAnimationSpec.hashCode()
        return result
    }

    companion object {
        val Saver = Saver<CarouselStateImpl, List<Any>>(
            save = { listOf(it.currentValue, it.range.start, it.range.endInclusive) },
            restore = {
                CarouselStateImpl(
                    currentValue = it[0] as Float,
                    range = (it[1] as Int)..(it[2] as Int)
                )
            }
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun rememberCarouselState(
    currentValue: Float = 0f,
    range: ClosedRange<Int> = 0..40,
): CarouselState {
    val state = rememberSaveable(saver = CarouselStateImpl.Saver) {
        CarouselStateImpl(currentValue, range)
    }
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
        state.snapTo(state.currentValue.roundToInt().toFloat())
    }
    return state
}

@Composable
fun InstagramCarousel(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    state: CarouselState = rememberCarouselState(),
    numSegments: Int = 5,
    circleColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface,
    currentValueLabel: @Composable (Int) -> Unit = { value -> Text(value.toString()) },
    indicatorLabel: @Composable (Int) -> Unit = { value -> Text(value.toString()) },
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    Column(
        modifier = modifier,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        currentValueLabel(state.currentValue.roundToInt())
        //Icon(Icons.Filled.ArrowDropDown, contentDescription = null)
        val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

        BoxWithConstraints(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .drag(state, numSegments),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        ) {

                CenterCircle(
                    modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center),
                    fillColor = Color(android.graphics.Color.parseColor("#4DB6AC")),
                    strokeWidth = 5.dp,
                )

            val segmentWidth = maxWidth / numSegments
            val segmentWidthPx = constraints.maxWidth.toFloat() / numSegments.toFloat()
            val halfSegments = (numSegments + 1) / 2
            val start = (state.currentValue - halfSegments).toInt()
                .coerceAtLeast(state.range.start)
            val end = (state.currentValue + halfSegments).toInt()
                .coerceAtMost(state.range.endInclusive)


            val maxOffset = constraints.maxWidth / 2f
            for (i in start..end) {
                val offsetX = (i - state.currentValue) * segmentWidthPx
                // alpha
                val deltaFromCenter = (offsetX)
                val percentFromCenter = 1.0f - abs(deltaFromCenter) / maxOffset
                val alpha = 0.25f + (percentFromCenter * 0.75f)
                // scale
                val deltaFromCenterScale = (offsetX)
                val percentFromCenterScale = 1.0f - abs(deltaFromCenterScale) / maxOffset
                val scale = 0.5f + (percentFromCenterScale * 0.5f)

                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .width(segmentWidth)
                        .wrapContentHeight(Alignment.CenterVertically)
                        .graphicsLayer(
                            translationX = offsetX,
                        ),
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                ) {

                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .width(55.dp)
                            .height(55.dp)
                            .graphicsLayer(
                                alpha = alpha,
                                scaleY = scale,
                                scaleX = scale
                            )
                            .clip(CircleShape)
                            .background(colors[i % colors.size])
                            .clickable {
                                scope.launch {
                                    state.scrollTo(i)
                                }
                                Toast
                                    .makeText(context, "$i", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show()
                            }
                    )
                    // indicatorLabel(i)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@SuppressLint("ReturnFromAwaitPointerEventScope", "MultipleAwaitPointerEventScopes")
private fun Modifier.drag(
    state: CarouselState,
    numSegments: Int,
) = pointerInput(Unit) {
    val decay = splineBasedDecay<Float>(this)
    val segmentWidthPx = size.width / numSegments
    coroutineScope {
        while (true) {
            val pointerId =
                awaitPointerEventScope { awaitFirstDown(pass = PointerEventPass.Initial).id }
            state.stop()
            val tracker = VelocityTracker()
            awaitPointerEventScope {
                horizontalDrag(pointerId) { change ->
                    val horizontalDragOffset =
                        state.currentValue - change.positionChange().x / segmentWidthPx
                    launch {
                        state.snapTo(horizontalDragOffset)
                    }
                    tracker.addPosition(change.uptimeMillis, change.position)
                    if (change.positionChange() != Offset.Zero) change.consume()
                }
            }
            val velocity = tracker.calculateVelocity().x / numSegments
            val targetValue = decay.calculateTargetValue(state.currentValue, -velocity)
            launch {
                state.decayTo(velocity, targetValue)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Preview(widthDp = 420)
@Composable
fun InstagramCarouselPreview() {
    ComposeLearningTheme() {
        Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
            InstagramCarousel(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .clickable {
                    }
                    .padding(vertical = 16.dp),
                currentValueLabel = { value ->
                    Text(
                        text = "${(value / 10)}.${(value % 10)}x",
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6
                    )
                },
                indicatorLabel = { value ->
                    if (value % 5 == 0) {
                        Text(
                            text = "${(value / 10)}.${(value % 10)}",
                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2,
                        )
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Screen Shot
[image]

Third way using custom layouts is here https://medium.com/@raghunandan2005/creating-instagram-like-carousel-in-compose-92d65de943a. Pending : Get the center item index and also smooth scroll on click of item to center

You can customize this and implement the solution you need. The code snippets are self explanatory. Instead of circular box you can have circular images/buttons as well.